# Visual Basic or C# drag and drop image source url

Tags: c#, vb.net, drag-and-drop, imgur

I am wanting to create and compile a small little program that allows someone to run, drag and drop an image from a browser. I then want this program to pick out the source URL for this image and paste it into a text box form. I need to do this because I am later going to be making the program upload the said URL image to Imgur at a click of a button using the API but for now I'm looking to find a way to use drag-and-drop to my advantage. I also don't know whether it would be easier to use VB.net or C#.

Can anybody give me any clues to how I may do this?

Here is what I have so far..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Imgur_Album_Upload
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WireDragDrop(this.Controls);
        }
        private void WireDragDrop(Control.ControlCollection ctls)
        {
            foreach (Control ctl in ctls)
            {
                ctl.AllowDrop = true;
                ctl.DragEnter += ctl_DragEnter;
                ctl.DragDrop += ctl_DragDrop;
                WireDragDrop(ctl.Controls);

            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ctl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var textData = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;

            if (textData == null)
                return;

            messagebox.Text = textData;
            // Validate the URL in textData here
        }
        private void ctl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in that case, you need the help of the browser itself.

Comment: I've done alot of research and nothing has quite worked, just wondered if anybody had any ideas as I've ran out of luck

Comment: I thought it would work quite a lot like a clipboard grab, but this time a drag-and-drop

Comment: Does the URL come as metadata with the drag-and-dropped image?

Comment: Windows forms using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: I see this example but I don't know if I'll experience the same problems as him http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055965/drag-and-drop-image-from-browser-to-wpf-application

Comment: Ah, I see. I was wrong about the format. Does the answer work for you? What if you get the data as `DataFormats.Text`?

Comment: And where would you put that?

Comment: Your control's `DragEnter` or `DragDrop` event handler. Here's a walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0%28v=vs.110%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in the [question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055965/drag-and-drop-image-from-browser-to-wpf-application) only seems to work with *some* browsers. Using "FileContents" in `GetData` doesn't work in Chrome for me, but works with Firefox. `DataFormats.Dib` would allow you to work with the bitmap directly, but unfortunately Chrome doesn't seem to support this one either.

Specifying `DataFormats.Text` seems to be a reliable cross-browser solution, as it returns the image's URL with all of the browsers I tested with. `DataFormats.UnicodeText` might be better, but I didn't test it.

First, set the `AllowDrop` property to `true` in whichever control you want to respond to drag-and-drop. Then, add these event handlers to the `DragEnter` and `DragDrop` events:

```
private void DragEnterHandler(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}

private void DragDropHandler(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var textData = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;

    if (textData == null)
        return;

    MessageBox.Show(textData);
    // Validate the URL in textData here
}
```

Visual Studio's designer can do this for you. Alternatively, you can add the handlers yourself, for example in your form's constructor:

```
this.DragEnter += DragEnterHandler;
this.DragDrop += DragDropHandler;
// someControl.DragEnter += DragEnterHandler;
// ...
```

Comment: How would you make it so you can drag an image anywhere on the form and it will enter it into a message box? I don't think it will be sufficient enough to require you to drag it to the message box.

Comment: @user4191887 I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17014821/996081) answer helps.

Comment: I've tried and it still doesn't work, when I drag it to the text box it just opens a dialogue with the image url in it

Comment: @user4191887 That was just an example to show you the data you dropped into the form. Replace `MessageBox.Show` with whatever you want.

Comment: No, it doesn't give me an option to drag and drop

Comment: Okay, I've got it working so when you drag it into the text box it pastes the data, it works. But I've used the code from the other example and it won't let me drag onto anything else, only the message box

Comment: @user4191887 Can you edit your answer to include youe current code? What "message box" are you talking about?

Comment: I've set it to enter the url into a text box, but this only works when you drag and drop the image over the text box. I want it so you can drop an image anywhere and it will put the url in the text box

Comment: @user4191887 Can you add a `MessageBox.Show` or something inside the DragDrop handler to confirm that it's even fired? What you described sounds like default text box behavior. Try running the program without debugging - I've heard that debugging the program breaks drag and drop since the host process runs with elevated permissions.

Comment: It does fire, I already tested it and it displays a message box with the url, but when I set it to enter that url into a text box. It doesn't work if you drop it anywhere else other than the text box itself

Comment: I've further tested that it only lets me drag and drop an image onto objects, never the actual form

Comment: @user4191887 You haven't wired the event handler to the form itself.

Comment: @user4191887 Well, you already have the code for adding event handlers to a control's event (`WireDragDrop`). Just do the same thing with `this`. See the end of this answer.

Comment: Drat, I can't find an example anywhere of how to use OAuth2 to authenticate as a user and upload to an album on Imgur. They should really have some detailed documentation on this kind of stuff.

Comment: @user4191887 You might want to look into existing .NET implementations and how they do it. One such example would be [EasyImgur](https://github.com/bkeiren/EasyImgur).

Comment: AntiVirus says that program is a no-go

Comment: @user4191887 You're supposed to be looking at the source code.

Comment: Yes and I am, but the program only allows a user to upload a picture, it doesn't further provide the option to upload it into a certain album. These things really should be documented, I say again.

Comment: @user4191887 Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103522/discussion-between-cubrr-and-user4191887).